# Comparing model and data using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to compare a set of discrete data values with a model to estimate the "x" value where there is a good match between the discrete data points and the model. In other words, I'm trying to estimate the x value (or the range of x) where the differences between data (discrete points) and the model are minimum. I've a model that provides Ya(x), Yb(x), Yc(x) (continuous lines). I also have the data points A, B and C (filled circles). I would like to estimate the x value where the data points A, B and C (or most of the points) match well with the corresponding continuous line. I also plot the (model-data)^2 as a function of x. It appears from the second plot that a good match can be obtained for the x range 5.e3 to 1.e4. I was wondering if I may use any scipy.optimize subroutine to estimate it quantitatively.

[image]

Thanks for your time and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comparing one data point to a curve isn't much to go on! In particular look at curve A - there are multiple places on the whole curve where your singular data point y-value would be a "good fit", and no way to determine which is "right".

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for your comment. I want to fit the three points simultaneously to the respective continuous lines of same colors. The discrete points are the values of the given variables (A, B and C) at a particular x. I want to estimate the x value by using the model. The idea is to put these points at different x positions and then compare the differences between data and model and eventually determine the x value where the differences are minimum for all the three points simultaneously. Please let me know if it makes sense now. Sorry that my description was not clear.

Comment: OK, so your curves A,B,C are fixed functions, and you want to vary x to find the minimum difference? So, write a function f(x,params), where the params are your three points. That function will compute, for x, the deviation of your three functions from the three points. Note that given the orders of magnitude differences in the functions, you might think of computing using the relative deviations rather than absolute deviations.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for your reply. I'm now using the relative deviations and I've three curves like the second plot. The minima of these three curve should tell me the value of X where a good fit can be obtained between the model and data. I was wondering what would be the best way to find the common minima of these three curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be some pseudo-code to get you started.  See if this actually matches what you want.

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np

def yA(x):
    # whatever calculations here you do for curve A
    return(1.0) # return whatever yA is at x
def yB(x):
    # whatever calculations here you do for curve B
    return(1.0) # return whatever yB is at x
def yC(x):
    # whatever calculations here you do for curve C
    return(1.0) # return whatever yC is at x

def func(x,data):
    A,B,C = data # unpack tuple
    devA = np.abs((yA(x)-A)/yA(x)) # normalize the deviations
    devB = np.abs((yB(x)-B)/yB(x)) # to account for the order
    devC = np.abs((yC(x)-C)/yC(x)) # of magnitude variations
    return(devA+devB+devC) # you want to minimize the sum of the deviations

A = 1.0E-10 # these are your data points (rough guess from plot)
B = 1.0E-11
C = 1.0E-8
x0 = 1000.0 # an initial guess

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(func,x0,args=(A,B,C))

print(result.x)
```